# How to Display Color With colorWithHue: in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, colors, uicolor

I have a color on the [Mac color wheel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kIZhe.png) and I want to display that color programmatically in my program in Xcode 5.

How do I do so with the `colorWithHue:` method of `UIColor`? How do I find the **Hue**, **Saturation**, and **Brightness** of the color?

*P.S. My color isn't the one on the image.*

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After you pick color in color wheel switch to "Color sliders" tab and choose "HSB sliders" option [image]

You should be able to see values for each color component on that screen